# Arrow looks very strange in a simple 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I try to plot an arrow in a very simple 3D plot. But the arrow and especially the arrowhead look very strange, which is certainly not the normal case. No matter how I change the parameters, it just doesn't get fixed.[image: the plot]

```
bias = 12; range0 = 1; range1 = 0.8;
h[x_, y_] := Sqrt[95 (x^2 + y^2) + bias^2];
arrow = Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[0.01], 
    Arrow[Tube[{{range1, -range1, -10}, {range1, -range1, 10}}, 
      0.02]]}];
Show[Plot3D[{h[x, y], -h[x, y]}, {x, -range0, range0}, {y, -range0, 
   range0}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-18.2, 20}}], arrow]
```

Comment: That is because of a ratio of scale of z axis relative to x/y

Comment: Try adding `BoxRatios -> Automatic`.

Comment: @J.M. It doesn't help much...

Comment: Did you add it to `Show[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, it becomes extremely narrow.

Comment: Yes, that's because the scales are different, as Kuba said. But the arrow is now undistorted.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. But is there a real cure?

Comment: Your two surfaces are too far away from each other, why not shift them closer?